# ForBiddenError in Node.js/Express.js/Angular2

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, angular

I am modifying [this GitHub sample app](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter) to use Express instead of KOA.  But I am getting an `Access Denied` error when the `/` route in Express tries to load the [`index.html`](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter/blob/master/client/index.html).  **What specific changes need to be made to the code below so that the new `/` route can successfully serve the `index.html`?**

The only changes made to the sample app are to modify `router.js`, to replace `index.js`, and to modify `package.json`.  I will show the changes as follows:

---

`router.js`

---

Here are the new relevant parts [`router.js`](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter/blob/master/server/router.js), with the old content omitted for brevity.  Noet that I added a `*` route to handle requests for `/` and I added `module.exports = function(app)`:

```
'use strict';

// expose the routes to our app with module.exports
module.exports = function(app) {

    //other routes omitted for brevity

    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
        console.log('inside / route!');
        res.sendfile('../client/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the front-end)
    });
};
```

---

`server/index.js`

---

Here is the new [`server/index.js`](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter/blob/master/server/index.js):

```
// set up ======================================================================
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();                               // create our app w/ express
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;                // set the port
var morgan = require('morgan');             // log requests to the console (express4)
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');    // pull information from HTML POST (express4)
var methodOverride = require('method-override'); // simulate DELETE and PUT (express4)

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));                 // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(morgan('dev'));                                         // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));            // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                     // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/'));

// load the routes
require('./router')(app);

// listen (start app with node server.js) ======================================
app.listen(port);
console.log("App listening on port " + port);
```

---

`package.json`

---

The new package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-esnext-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/index.js",
    "test": "COVERAGE_ENABLED=true gulp test",
    "webdriver-update": "webdriver-manager update"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter.git"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "blacksonic",
    "email": "soos.gabor86@gmail.com"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "keywords": [
    "angular2",
    "es6",
    "webpack",
    "gulp"
  ],
  "description": "Angular 2 development in Javascript with ES6/ES7 syntax powered by Babel.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "4.4.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "jsonwebtoken": "7.0.1",
    "morgan": "^1.1.1",
    "method-override": "^2.1.3",

    "node-uuid": "1.4.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",
    "babel-core": "6.10.4",
    "babel-eslint": "6.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-__coverage__": "11.0.0",
    "babel-preset-angular2": "0.0.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.9.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.6",
    "codeclimate-test-reporter": "0.3.3",
    "del": "2.2.1",
    "es6-promise": "3.2.1",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-cssnano": "2.1.2",
    "gulp-delete-lines": "0.0.7",
    "gulp-eslint": "3.0.1",
    "gulp-less": "3.1.0",
    "gulp-nodemon": "2.1.0",
    "gulp-protractor": "2.4.0",
    "gulp-util": "3.0.7",
    "gulp-watch": "4.3.8",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "karma": "1.1.1",
    "karma-coverage": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "1.7.0",
    "localStorage": "1.0.3",
    "mini-lr": "0.1.9",
    "phantomjs-polyfill": "0.0.2",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.7",
    "protractor": "3.3.0",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "run-sequence": "1.2.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "validate.js": "0.10.0",
    "webpack": "1.13.1",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  }
}
```

---

Error Message

---

Here is the complete error message which prints in FireFox:

```
ForbiddenError: Forbidden
   at SendStream.error (/home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2_oauth_seed_app/node_modules/send/index.js:275:31)
   at SendStream.pipe (/home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2_oauth_seed_app/node_modules/send/index.js:508:12)
   at sendfile (/home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2_oauth_seed_app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1051:8)
   at ServerResponse.res.sendfile (/home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2_oauth_seed_app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:481:3)
   at ServerResponse.eval [as sendfile] (eval at wrapfunction (/home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2_oauth_seed_app/node_modules/depd/index.js:413:5), <anonymous>:4:11)
   at /home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2_oauth_seed_app/server/router.js:94:17
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2_oauth_seed_app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
   at next (/home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2_oauth_seed_app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
   at Route.dispatch (/home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2_oauth_seed_app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2_oauth_seed_app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error comes from res.sendfile(../); you cannot sendFile with a relative path as express considers this a security concern. To solve this, require the path module and use `path.resolve('/wherever/youre/going')` instead of a relative path.

Comment: Thank you and +1.  Yes, I actually had found that myself.  But there is a downstream problem of figuring out which `index.html` file in that app to send as the root of the Angular2 app.  When I send either `client/index.html` or `dist/client/index.html`, the browser console complains in ways that indicate it cannot read ES6.  Somehow, the KOA code avoids this problem, but the express.js code so far is not able to serve a working Angular2/ES6 app.